# How to freeze gridview Header when gridview is getting from xslt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Previously to freeze headers am using this code

```
top: expression(document.getElementById("gridPanel").scrollTop-2);
left:expression(parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.scrollLeft);
position:fixed;
z-index: 10;
```

this is working fine upto ie7 but when making to edge mode it is not working.
and also am getting table dynamically from xslt. I have tried jquery and javascripts but it is not working.

Comment: CSS expressions are not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and later. [**About Dynamic Properties**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @DavidDomain Kindly tell me the replacement for expressions.Thanks in Advance